# Pass implementation of functional interface as parameter

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

Functional Interface is described like this:

```java
package models;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface EventReducer {
    void apply(Event event, GameState state);
}
```

I implement the interface in the following class:

```java
package models.reducers;

import models.Event;
import models.EventReducer;
import models.GameState;
import models.events.MinionDeathEvent;

public class MinionDeath implements EventReducer {

    @Override
    public void apply(Event event, GameState state) {
        MinionDeathEvent deathEvent = (MinionDeathEvent)event;
        deathEvent.getPlayer().getBoard().remove(deathEvent.getMinion());
    }
}
```

How can I pass the implementation as a parameter? For example,

```java
    private static final Map<EventType, EventReducer> ReducersMap = Map.ofEntries(
        entry(EventType.DEATH, MinionDeath::apply);
    );
```

Apparently, `MinionDeath::apply` is not a way to go

Comment: You need to instantiate a new instance of `MinionDeath` and pass it along as paprameter: `entry(EventType.DEATH, new MinionDeath());`. --- As an aside: you are missing a semicolon after `entry(...)`

Comment: Do I have to init it? there is not way with ::?

Comment: Not if you implement it as separate class, no. What you could do is transform it into an expression lambda: `entry(EventType.DEATH, (event, state) -> ((MinionDeathEvent) event).getPlayer().getBoard().remove(deathEvent.getMinion()));`

Comment: Please, create an answer if you fancy points

Comment: Your `EventReducer` seems pretty similar to a [`BiConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html). Did you not want to bring in the awareness of the type in implementation with something like `interface EventReducer<T> { void apply(T event, GameState state);}` followed by `new EventReducer<MinionDeathEvent> {

    @Override
    public void apply(MinionDeathEvent event, GameState state) {
        event.getPlayer().getBoard().remove(deathEvent.getMinion());
    }`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The problem

In the current solution, we try to reference an instance method without having an instance of a class

```
entry(EventType.DEATH, MinionDeath::apply);
```

The runtime is not able to create an instance of `MinionDeath` by itself, mainly because it is not guaranteed that a no-args constructor exists (it exists in this particular case, but not every class has a no-args constructor).

### Solutions

There are several possibilities to solve the problem. Here are some of them:

1. Create an instance of `MinionDeath`, pass it as argument.

   ```
   entry(EventType.DEATH, new MinionDeath());
   ```
2. Lambda expression: This is basically inlining the implementation of `MinionDeath` diretcly into the lambda.

   ```
   entry(
       EventType.DEATH, 
       (event, state) -> ((MinionDeathEvent) event).getPlayer()
               .getBoard()
               .remove(deathEvent.getMinion()));
   ```
3. Define the lambda as, e.g., static method, pass it as method reference.

   ```
   public class Game { // The class name is an assumption of mine

       ...

       private static void processMonsterDeathEvent(Event event, GameState state) {
           MinionDeathEvent deathEvent = (MinionDeathEvent)event;
           deathEvent.getPlayer().getBoard().remove(deathEvent.getMinion());
       }

       private static final Map<EventType, EventReducer> ReducersMap = Map.ofEntries(
           entry(EventType.DEATH, Game::processMonsterDeathEvent)
       );

       ...
   }
   ```

   A remark on this solution: This is different from the original solution since we are now referencing a static method. We could also change method `apply` in `MinionDeath` to be `static`. In this case, we should remove the `... implements EventRecorder` from the class definition since it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass an instance of the `MinionDeath` as long as it *is* a functional interface itself with exactly one abstract method, therefore is qualified. Also `MinionDeath` is `EventReducer` and is assignable into that class.

```
private static final Map<EventType, EventReducer> ReducersMap = Map.ofEntries(
    entry(EventType.DEATH, new MinionDeath())
);
```

Note this is effectively as same as you pass the lambda expression itself:

```
private static final Map<EventType, EventReducer> ReducersMap = Map.ofEntries(
    entry(
        EventType.DEATH,                                                      // key
        (event, state) -> {                                                   // value
            MinionDeathEvent deathEvent = (MinionDeathEvent)event;
            deathEvent.getPlayer().getBoard().remove(deathEvent.getMinion());
        }
    )
);
```

Also note, if you write `entry(EventType.DEATH, MinionDeath::apply)`, it is not what you want and a new functional interface compatible with such lambda expression would have been created:

```
interface TriConsumer<T,R,S> {
    void consume(T t, R r, S s);
}
```

```
Map<EventType, TriConsumer<MinionDeath, Event, GameState>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(EventType.DEATH, MinionDeath::apply);
```

Comment: Yes and no. I want to provide a more straightforward answer with an explanation what `MinionDeath::apply` would be.